# Excel percentage between todays date and due date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula, percentage

So i need to complete a dashboard and then turn the percentage results into a chart, to see where we are in a Yearly Plan. Lets say the column/the task is "i have to renovate the bedroom", i need a column for the closing date (when i do it) and a row for the due date (lets say 30.06.2023). I need the percentage to calculate how much time i have left until the due date. But if the task is done before the due date, the percentage should be 100%. This should calculate as if daily the percentage is increasing as if i take daily actions, and i get closer to the 100% approaching the due date. I am stuck for 2 h trying different formulas, nothing seems to work. Help would be highly appreciated!

I tried everything i could that i knew of. But nothing seems to calculate between todays date and the due date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for you.

first, build a table like this:

[image: how the table should look like]

then, in the column "ClosingDate" you will write:

```
="X"
```

next, in the column "TimePass%" you will write:

```
=IF([@ClosingDate]<=[@DueDate],1,IF([@ClosingDate]="X",1-(DAYS([@DueDate],NOW())/DAYS([@DueDate],[@StartingDate]))))
```

[image: this is how the formula should look like]

then:

- when you didn't finish the task the table automatically write "X" and the it will calculate the time passed in %.
- when you finished task earlier it will write 100%.

hope that helps.

*****the dates in here are in this format: DD/MM/YYYY***** same will work for other formats.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your help!! I can not get past one error in order to see if this formula would work for me. "The syntax of this name isnt correct" but i checked and double checked and cant seem to find the problem. I also copied extacly the table and same problem appears :(. Could you maybe guide me through this also? Thank you again for your great support!

Comment: hey Bianca, it might be because your not putting the formula inside a Table? maybe outside of the table? this formula works only inside the table. you can try use this formula, that replace "[@closingDate]" ext with this: =IF(D2<=C2,1,IF(D2="X",1-(DAYS(C2,NOW())/DAYS(C2,B2)))) but please if I didn't get it right can you show a picture of it?

Comment: Hello! Yes, this formula works perfectly! Thank you so much!! I was writting the first one in the table. I have one question: if i were to check weekly the status, would the percentage rise because i am getting closer to the Due Date? Or i would have to update something manually in order to show the progress in time? Thank you!

Comment: It will rise automaticlly because it is calculate with the “now()” function. Therefore it will rise without doing nothing. Happy to help (: Mark the answer above as ok to help others!